# How to pass options to a new IronPython engine?

Tags: ironpython

I am hosting IronPython within IronPython. I did not find the way to initialize it with the equivalent of the command line argument: `-X:FullFrames`.

My code is somewhat like that:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('IronPython')
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Scripting')
from IronPython.Hosting import PythonCommandLine, PythonConsoleOptions, Python
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Dynamic')
clr.AddReference('System')
import System
from Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Shell import IConsole

engine = Python.CreateEngine()
runtime = engine.Runtime
for assembly in clr.References:
    runtime.LoadAssembly(assembly)

cmdLine = PythonCommandLine()
runtime.Globals.SetVariable('cur_cmdLine',cmdLine)

cmdLine.Run(engine, my_console(), PythonConsoleOptions())
```

"my" code is based on [this](http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2009-May/010267.html) and [that](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/ip_in_ip.shtml).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
engine = Python.CreateEngine({'FullFrames': True})
```

and the full frames will be enabled.  All the other options match up w/ the command line options.